# Auto click bullets on slider to make slider autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a custom slider which can rotate each image when i click the bullets. i need to make it autoplay, so i want if the page is ready, it's trigger click on the 1st bullet, then 2nd, and back to 1st bullet again...

the bullets using attr `data-container` for each slide `id` :

```
<nav class="thumb-nav">
        <a data-container="container-1" class="thumb-nav__item" href="#"><span>1</span></a>
        <a data-container="container-2" class="thumb-nav__item" href="#"><span>2</span></a>
    </nav>
```

and these are the slide contents :

```
<div id="container-1" class="container theme-1">
        <header class="intro">
            <img class="intro__image" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/img/header01.jpg" alt="Lava"/>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div id="container-2" class="container theme-2">
        <header class="intro">
            <img class="intro__image" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/img/header02.jpg" alt="Road"/>
        </header>

    </div>
```

and here's my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdp1708/qedgznxx/)

Any help is going to be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` function to do this.
And in you code:

```
pageTriggers.forEach( function( pageTrigger ) {
pageTrigger.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    navigate( this );
    console.log(pageTrigger);
} );
setInterval(function() {
    navigate( pageTrigger );
}, 5000);
```

} );

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9fupL7hc/1

Ok, i updated the code:

```
var id = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    id ++;
    if ( id <= document.querySelectorAll(".container").length ) {
        navigate( document.querySelector('a[data-container="container-' + id + '"') );
    } else {
        id = 1;
    }
}, 5000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9fupL7hc/8/

Comment: hi @Radonirina . thanks, 
but when i add the 3rd slide, it just work for 1st and 2nd slide .
any suggestion?
http://jsfiddle.net/vdp1708/9fupL7hc/2/